# tar a folder minus one sub-folder

Tags: tar

I'm trying to create a tar archive of a folder `thisfolder` but want to omit a sub-folder named `notthisfolder`.  Can someone show me how to do this? I've tried to tar'ing the entire folder and removing the one I want to omit but that particular folder is 17gb.

```
\thisfolder
  file1
  file2
  \notthisfolder
    omitfile1
    omitfile2
  \butincludethisfolder
    includefile1
    infludefile2
```

I was using `tar --exclude='notthisfolder' -zcvpf archive.tar /thisfolder/`

Comment: Can you post your tar script?

Comment: @troylatroy, I'm not sure exactly but the tar script I'm using is only omitting files in `notthisfolder` but everything else in its subfolder is being included... =(

Answer (score 2):

Your command is almost correct. Use

```
 tar cvfzp achive.tar.gz --exclude notthisfolder thisfolder/
```

1. Note that the `--exclude notthisfolder` option goes *after* the archive name.
2. Cosmetic comment: when using the `z` option, you are using gzip to compress your tarball, so name the archive `archive.tar.gz` and not `archive.tar`.
3. Also, `/thisfolder/` is an absolute path and points to the folder `thisfolder` inside the root directory `/`. For specifying a relative path (to the current working directory), use `thisfolder/` without the leading slash `/`.
4. As a little tidbit, you don't need to prefix the `cvfzp` options with a `-`. One less character to type!

Works for me ;)

```
$ tree
.
└── thisfolder
    ├── butincludethisfolder
    │   ├── includefile1
    │   └── includefile2
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    └── notthisfolder
        └── notthisfile

3 directories, 6 files

$ tar cvfzp achive.tar.gz --exclude notthisfolder thisfolder/
thisfolder/
thisfolder/butincludethisfolder/
thisfolder/butincludethisfolder/includefile1
thisfolder/butincludethisfolder/includefile2
thisfolder/file1
thisfolder/file2
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you syntax is wrong.

It should be more like this:

`tar -zcvpf /where/you/store/backups/archive.tar /thisfolder --exclude "/notthisfolder" --exclude "/notthisfolder/omitfile1" --exclude "/notthisfolder/omitfile2"`

or if the omit files are all in `/notthisfolder`

`tar -zcvpf /where/you/store/backups/archive.tar /thisfolder --exclude "/notthisfolder"`

Answer (score 0):

From `man tar`:

```
 --exclude=PATTERN
       exclude files, given as a PATTERN
```

So, given a directory like this:

```
terdon@oregano foo $ tree
.
└── thisfolder
    ├── butincludethisfolder
    │   ├── includefile1
    │   └── includefile2
    └── notthisfolder
        ├── omitfile1
        └── omitfile2
```

You could run the following `tar` command to get what you want:

```
tar -cvzf foo.tar --exclude notthisfolder thisfolder/
```

That will create `tar.foo` which contains:

```
$ tar xvzf foo.tar 
thisfolder/
thisfolder/butincludethisfolder/
thisfolder/butincludethisfolder/includefile2
thisfolder/butincludethisfolder/includefile1
```